# What is the meaning of below verses from Vishnu yamala and are similar verses found in any other tantras?

Tags: tantra

Sanatana Goswami, a Gaudiya Vaishnava acharya quoted in his book Hari Bhakti Vilas, a smrti text for Gaudya Vaishnavas the following verses from Vishnu Yamala in the beginning of 5th Vilasa.

> Agamoktena mArgeNa bhagavAn brAhmaNair api | sadaiva pUjyo.ato lekhyaH
>   prAya Agamiko vidhiH ||3||
>
> tathA ca viShNu-yAmale— kR^ite shruty-ukta-mArgaH syAt tretAyAM
>   smR^iti-bhAvitaH | dvApare tu purANoktaH kalAv Agama-sambhavaH ||4||
>   ashuddhAH shUdrAkalpA hi brAhmaNAH kali-sambhavAH | teShAm
>   Agama-mArgeNa shuddhir na shrauta-vartmanA ||5||
>
> Commentaryof 
>   sanAtanaH: teShAm Agama-mArgeNa shrauta-vartmanety anena tair api
>   Agamika-vidhinaiva pUjA kAryeti bhAvaH | tathA caikAdasha-skandhe [BhP
>   11.5.31] nAnA-tantra-vidhAnena kalAv api tathA shR^iNu iti | tatra shrIdhara-svAmi-pAdAH—nAnA-tantra-vidhAneneti kalau tantra-mArgasya
>   prAdhAnyaM darshayati iti ||3-5||

Hindi translation is here:

[image]

In Satya yuga, Vedic rules, in Treta smarta method, in Dvapara through puranas, and in Kali rules prescribed by Agamas are to be followed.

The worship of Bhagavan is done following tantras primarily in Kali yuga and purification happens through this only.

And in Kali yuga, Brahmanas are impure like sudras and purification happens through methods prescribed in tantras not Vedic rules.

Does it mean that the process prescribed in other yugas are completely ineffective? Are the similar type of verses found in any other tantras?

Comment: Yes in [Mahanirvana Tantra](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tantra/maha/index.htm) also, similar thing is told.

Comment: Vishnu Yāmala is a Bhairava Agama.

Comment: Its recommended to adopt agamic path but does not mean denouncing Vedic path. As Vedas are eternal and agamas also trace origins from Vedas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes similar verses are there in other Tantras.

The [Brihat TantrasAra](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm) quotes verses from the scripture called TArA Pradip:

> TArA Pradip:
>
> Agamokta vidhAnena kalau devAn yajet sudhih |
>  Nahi devAh
>   prasidanti kalau chAnya vidhAnatah ||
>  Krite shrutyukto mArgah syAt
>   tretAyAm smriti sambhabah ||
>  DwApare tu purAnoktoh kalAvAgama
>   sammatah |
>  AshudhAh shudra karmAno brAhmanAh kalisambhavAh ||
>   TeshAmAgam mArgena siddhirna shrauta vartmanA ||
>
> In Kali Yuga, the wise should perform deity worship as per the rules
>   prescribed in the Agamas. In Kali Yuga the deities are not pleased if
>   worshipped by any other methods. In Satya Yuga the Veda prescribed
>   methods are to be followed; in TretA those of Smritis; in DwApara the
>   methods given in PurAnas should be followed but in Kali Yuga only
>   Agama prescribed methods should be followed. In Kali Yuga, the
>   BrAhmins are impure and they are of Shudra like conduct. That's why, besides
>   the Agama prescribed rites, they do not have rights over Veda prescribed
>   rites.

The MahAnirvAna Tantram's chapter 1 also has similar verses:

> **In this Age the Mantras of the Tantras are efficacious**, yield
>   immediate fruit, and are auspicious for Japa, Yajna, and all such
>   practices and ceremonies (14). **The Vedic rites and Mantras which were
>   efficacious in the First Age have ceased to be so in this**. They are
>   now as powerless as snakes, the poison−fangs of which are drawn and
>   are like to that which is dead (15). The whole heap of other Mantras
>   have no more power than the organs of sense of some pictured image on
>   a wall. To worship with the aid of other Mantras is as fruitless as it
>   is to cohabit with a barren woman. The labour is lost (16−17). He who
>   in this Age seeks salvation by ways prescribed by others is like a
>   thirsty fool who digs a well on the bank of the Jahnavi (18), and he
>   who, knowing My Dharmma, craves for any other is as one who with
>   nectar in his house yet longs for the poisonous juice of the akanda
>   plant (19). No other path is there to salvation and happiness in this
>   life or in that to come like unto that shown by the Tantras (20)

Comment: Add [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/what-is-the-position-of-the-tantras-among-the-holy-scriptures#comment97094_32104) too.

Comment: Which one? Can not understand

Comment: Click on the text "this one"

Comment: That is just a comment? @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: So, is this instruction related to Deity worship standards?

Comment: I meant, Add that in detail not just the comment,

Comment: means? can not understand @RaRe

Comment: Is this talking about worshipping arca vigraha? I understood now thanks.

Comment: It is talking abt Devata Puja i.e deity worship .. Deity worship can be done in Yantras too besides Vigraha (idols) .. the verse has "DevAn yajet" @RaRe

Comment: Ok.. Do you have full text of tantra you quoted from?

Comment: No only as much as is quoted in Tantrasara .. such Tantras are not extant now @RaRe

Comment: Yeah, I tried to find Vishnu Yamala, not available even in archive org. We have to be satisfied only with quoted portions elsewhere I think. :(

Comment: lol I added that as an answer too, thought you didn't understand what I meant @Rickross

Comment: Yes Vishnu Yamala, Brama Yamala etc are not existing even in Bengal where we can get all Tantric scriptures very easily  @RaRe

Comment: Oh ok .. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Rickross calling Shiva a Demi-God and accepting Shiva-vakya ---are these compatible? Tantra does not accept Sr Krishna as the only highest form of God!Some tantra calls Him just an incarnation of Maa Kali:)

Comment: @parthabanerjee thank you for sharing the love some tantras show towards Krishna by according him the status of at least incarnation of Kali maa. Oh by the way, congrats on the rocket speed 1000 rep. I am sure the community is happy to have such a knowledgeable person here.

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing is also there mentioned in [Mahanirvana_Tantra](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tantra/maha/maha02.htm)  :

> **In this Age the Mantras of the Tantras are efficacious, yield immediate fruit, and are auspicious for Japa, Yajna, and all such practices and ceremonies (14). The Vedic rites and Mantras which were efficacious in the First Age have ceased to be so in this.** They are now as powerless as snakes, the poison-fangs of which are drawn and are like to that which is dead (15). The whole heap of other Mantras have no more power than the organs of sense of some pictured image on a wall. To worship with the aid of other Mantras is as fruitless as it is to cohabit with a barren woman. The labour is lost (16-17). He who in this Age seeks salvation by ways prescribed by others is like a thirsty fool who digs a well on the bank of the Jahnavi (18), and he who, knowing My Dharmma, craves for any other is as one who with nectar in his house yet longs for the poisonous juice of the akanda plant (19). No other path is there to salvation and happiness in this life or in that to come like unto that shown by the Tantras (20). From my mouth have issued the several Tantras with their sacred legends and practices both for Siddhas and Sadhakas (21). At times, O My Beloved! by reason of the great number of men of the pashu disposition, as also of the diversity of the qualifications of men, it has been said that the Dharmma spoken of in the Kulachara Scriptures should be kept secret (22). But some portions of this Dharmma, O Beloved! have been revealed by Me with the object of inclining the minds of men thereto. Various kinds of Devata and worshippers are mentioned therein, such as Bhairava, Vetala, Vatuka, Nayika, Shaktas, Shaivas, Vaishnavas, Sauras, Ganapatyas, and others. In them, too, are described various Mantra and Yantra which aid men in the attainment of siddhi, and which, though they demand great and constant effort, yet yield the desired fruit (23-25). Hitherto My answer has been given according to the nature of the case and the questioner, and for his individual benefit only (26).