# Is Kaliyuga best time to get Moksha ? Is Bhakti only way to get Moksha in kaliyuga?

Tags: moksha, kali-yuga

1. Is Kaliyuga best time to get Moksha ?
2. Is Bhakti (by doing Bhajans ), only way to get Moksha in Kaliyuga , especially for a normal person  ?
   Of course following dharma (doing the right and moral thing) is also
   essential . As it the basis of living life.
   I don't find way other than Bhakti. Is it written in any scriptures.

   I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yb8A3QsF0U) mentioning Bhakti to Krishna is the way to go in Kaliyuga.
3. Towards whom should we dedicate our Bhakti ? Shiva ji or Krishna Bhagwan (Vishnu) or any other God ?

What is the truth ?

Comment: Similar - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46515/fastest-and-easiest-way-in-kaliyuga-to-attain-liberation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kaliyug is the best yuga for sankirtan.

**ध्यायन् कृते यजन् यज्ञैस्त्रेतायां द्रापरेऽर्च्चयन्।
यदाप्रोति तदाप्रोति कलौ श्रीरामसंकीर्तनात्।।**

Vishnu Puran

Whatever is achieved by meditation in Satya-yuga, by the performance of sacrifice in Treta-yuga, and by the worship of Lord Krsna’s lotus feet in Dvapara-yuga is obtained in the age of Kali simply by glorifying the name of Lord Shri Ram.

**सर्वेषां हरिनाम्ना हि वैभवं रामनामतः।
ज्ञातं मया विशेषेण तस्मात् श्रीरामनाम संजप।।**

(Padmapuran)

All the names of shri bhagwan eg vishnu, narayan, krishna, janardan, etc are created from the name of shri Ram. So just chant ram naam

**रामनामैव नामैव नामैव मम् जीवनम्।
कलौ नास्त्येव नास्त्येव नास्त्येव गतिरन्यथा॥**

Skandpuran

श्रीसनत्कुमार नारद जी से कहते हैं —श्री राम जी का नाम, केवल श्री राम नाम हीं, राम नाम हीं मेरा जीवन है । कलियुग में राम नाम के सिवाय और किसी उपाय से जीवो कि सद्गति नही होती, नहीं होती, नहीं होती ।

Sage Sanatkumāra said to sage Narada —

The name of Shri Rama, one and only ‘Rama’ Nama is my life. There is no other means, no other means and no other means except Shri Rama Nama in this Kaliyug for Jivas to attain the Liberation.

Towards whom we should dedicate our bhakti?

सर्वेषां वेदशास्त्राणां रहस्यते प्रकाशितम्।

एको देवो रामचन्द्र व्रतं एकोतदर्चनं।।

मंत्रोप्यकश्च तन्नाम शास्त्र तद ध्यवतत्स्तुति।

तस्मात् सर्वात्मना रामचन्द्रो भजमनोहरम्।।

यथा गोष्पवदवतुच्छो  भवेत् संसार मनोहरम्।।

Padmapuran patal khand chapter
35  shlok 50- 52

सारे वेद शास्त्र का रहस्य यही प्रकाशित है

एक ही भगवान ->श्री रामचन्द्र

एक ही व्रत-> उनका पुजा

एक ही मंत्र -> श्रीराम नाम

एक ही शास्त्र-> रामायण

इसलिए हर मनुष्य को चाहिए कि सर्वात्मा परमात्मा श्रीराम  का ही भजन करें ताकी संसार को गोपद के समान सुलभ ही पार कर सकें।।

The secret of all the Vedas is revealed in this

***One God -> Shri Ramchandra

only one fast-> his worship

One mantra -> Shri Ram Naam

One scripture-> Ramayana***

That's why every human being should worship the Supreme Soul Shri Ram only so that he can cross the world easily like a cow.

Answer (score 0):

I personally disagree with sectarian literature that is later compiled in Kaliyuga itself. But yes, for majority of the people Bhakti is the only path towards liberation.

Consider other sectarian literatures:

Tantrasara:

> TArA Pradip:
>
> Agamokta vidhAnena kalau devAn yajet sudhih | Nahi devAh prasidanti
> kalau chAnya vidhAnatah || Krite shrutyukto mArgah syAt tretAyAm
> smriti sambhabah || DwApare tu purAnoktoh kalAvAgama sammatah |
> AshudhAh shudra karmAno brAhmanAh kalisambhavAh || TeshAmAgam mArgena
> siddhirna shrauta vartmanA ||
>
> In Kali Yuga, the wise should perform deity worship as per the rules
> prescribed in the Agamas. In Kali Yuga the deities are not pleased if
> worshipped by any other methods. In Satya Yuga the Veda prescribed
> methods are to be followed; in TretA those of Smritis; in DwApara the
> methods given in PurAnas should be followed but in Kali Yuga only
> Agama prescribed methods should be followed. In Kali Yuga, the
> BrAhmins are impure and they are of Shudra like conduct. That's why,
> besides the Agama prescribed rites, they do not have rights over Veda
> prescribed rites.

Mahanirvana Tantra, Chapter 1:

> In this Age the Mantras of the Tantras are efficacious, yield
> immediate fruit, and are auspicious for Japa, Yajna, and all such
> practices and ceremonies (14). The Vedic rites and Mantras which were
> efficacious in the First Age have ceased to be so in this. They are
> now as powerless as snakes, the poison−fangs of which are drawn and
> are like to that which is dead (15). The whole heap of other Mantras
> have no more power than the organs of sense of some pictured image on
> a wall. To worship with the aid of other Mantras is as fruitless as it
> is to cohabit with a barren woman. The labour is lost (16−17). He who
> in this Age seeks salvation by ways prescribed by others is like a
> thirsty fool who digs a well on the bank of the Jahnavi (18), and he
> who, knowing My Dharmma, craves for any other is as one who with
> nectar in his house yet longs for the poisonous juice of the akanda
> plant (19). No other path is there to salvation and happiness in this
> life or in that to come like unto that shown by the Tantras (20)

ref: [What is the meaning of below verses from Vishnu yamala and are similar verses found in any other tantras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32307/what-is-the-meaning-of-below-verses-from-vishnu-yamala-and-are-similar-verses-fo)

Since Puranas are bhakti texts, you are most likely to be getting glorification of the particular sectarian deity and bhakti methods.

Similarly, Upanishads and Gitas such as Ashtavakra Gita glorify the path of knowledge, i.e. Gyan Yog.

The path of yoga is regarded as one of the fastest methods of liberation, yet very violent and dangerous in such cases. It is the job of your guru to chose what is best for you or alternatively search what suits you the most.

Comment: BG 12.6-7: But those who dedicate all their actions to Me, regarding Me as the Supreme goal, worshiping Me and meditating on Me with exclusive devotion, O Parth, I swiftly deliver them from the ocean of birth and death, for their consciousness is united with Me. (??)

Comment: @SaffronVajra Same Krishna to Arjuna:

*Therefore, the conviction that “I am Brahman“ is known to be the sole cause of
emancipation (moksha) for great souls (mahatmas).* | 44.

*As a hungry person simply wastes his energy in vain when he strikes the air with
blows, so too a reader of the Vedas and other shastras simply wastes his time and energy
if, notwithstanding his study, he fails to realize “I am Brahman.“* |47

Simply - faith in Krishna is the same as faith in self - there is no Krishna than self (or Omkara), similar intrepretation to Kashmir Shivaism.

Comment: 12.1 Arjuna said Those devotees who, being thus ever dedicated, meditate on You, and those again (who meditate) on the Immutable, the Unmanifested-of them, who are the best experiencers of yoga [(Here) yoga means samadhi, spiritual absorption.]

12.2 The Blessed Lord said Those who meditate on Me by fixing their minds on Me with steadfast devotion (and) being endowed with supreme faith-they are considered to be the most perfect yogis according to Me.

Comment: Yes. What's wrong here? Those who meditate on *me*, refer here to the syllable *om*. As Krishna defines himself as syllable *om*. In Upanishads, this is called Pranava Yoga and is the ultimate yoga of self-realization and liberation. I don't see anything wrong here? I've acknowledged yogic versions of liberation in my answer too.

Comment: Krishna describes himself as a lot of things, that does not mean contemplation on Krishna was meant to be restricted to that one thing only, the 12th chapter starts off with a discussion on contemplation of Krishna as the Brahman vs as the Lord incarnate.

Comment: *Krishna describes himself as a lot of things...*, No, that's rather opposite. Krishna defined himself as a syllable om [7.8, 9.17, 10.25, 6.13, 8.12-14] and Omkara is everywhere [viz. Mandukya Upanishad]. If you assume a human figure like Krishna as equivalent to omkara, i.e. creator, sustainer, and destroyer, then you can meditate on him too, that's also one way if one doesn't want to stick to sounds. Similarly other people choose Shiva like figure (like - Krishna himself), or any.

Comment: Literally the entire 10th chapter is Krishna describing himself to be a vast number of things, because he is the Brahman itself, the inner Lord who is situated in the heart of beings yet is manifested Infront of Arjuna, surrender unto that form.

Comment: @SaffronVajra I literally said, just as *om* is everywhere, *Krishna* as *om* could also be everywhere, including everything in *Chapter - 10*, just like *self*, because *Krishna* defines himself as *om*, so everything written in Chapter -10 is valid.

Comment: Youre acting like Om is the only quality which the Brahman has or something and everything else just follows, this is the wrong interpretation of the Upanisads

Comment: No. My interpretation is rather the opposite. Om is brahman and everything else that is represented via om can also be said to be brahman. If you don't agree, cite from Upanishads.

Comment: Brahman can be contemplated on as Aum, but that doesn't mean Om is literally Brahman.

Comment: @SaffronVajra Please read Upanishads properly. OM is PRANAVA (BRAHMAN). All Upanishads - from Mandukya Upanishad to Chandogya Upanishad have directly written that. In Yoga Upanishads Om is a route to self, which is declared Brahman (similar to what Krishna said). All your scriptures and knowledge is futile if you haven't realized that.

Comment: If you think that Om (the sound) is literally Brahman, then i'm afraid you haven't at all understood what Yajnavalkya was talking about, the Upanishads also say that sky is Brahman and Ether is Brahman, does not mean that literally they re brahman, the Brahman is not an object

Comment: @SaffronVajra Which Upanishad says *sky is brahman* or *ether is brahman*? This is wrong.

Comment: What's wrong is you imposing an attribute to the Brahman, Brahman is neither Aum nor is it Akasha, but the Ultimate can be contemplated on on the basis of various forms. Read :- https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62768.html

Comment: @SaffronVajra I already said any Upanishad or text that says *either* is *brahman* is simply wrong. What you are showing is mere आकाशस्तल्लिङ्गात्, i.e. *akasha* which is simply *brahman* in *Samkhya* philosophy and talks about characteristic marks of that. I don't think you are even understanding what you are citing. In any case, please make some sense before adding any random verse. Pranava (or om) is brahman because it leads one to ultimate real self, brahman, that is represented via *ishavara* in dualistic philosophy. I don't think you are understanding even the minute basics here.

Comment: Original Vedas or Upanishads rarely do even talk about forms of the Ishvara, they are heavily concentrated on Omkara, unless some special texts.

Comment: Definitely buddy, both Sankaracharya and Yajnavalkya are wrong, Brahman does have a specific characteristic excluding other characteristics. Brahman is neither Omkara nor is it Akasha, Brahman is not some sound or vibration or someshit

Comment: @SaffronVajra Who is Shankaracharya or Yajnavalkya? I'm only citing Krishna. It is only via meditation on Omkara, one knows Brahman (Uttara Gita 1.5). Is Krishna wrong too?

Comment: Who is Yajnavalkya and who is Sankaracharya? What? I thought we were discussing Gita vis-a-vis Upanishads since I pointed out that Krishna describes himself as many things?

Comment: @SaffronVajra Yes. This is why I've said since om only leads to brahman, it is brahman as sound itself. Om is everywhere hence, it is brahman and therefore Krishna defines himself as om so that he is also omnipresent.

Comment: Krishna describes himself as 1000 different things, Om is just one way of expression, the Brahman has no attributes.

Comment: @SaffronVajra All brahman can be described as 1000 things. Om is brahman, this is why Krishna becomes brahman.

Comment: Om is one of those 1000 things

Comment: @SaffronVajra Om is everything

Answer (score 0):

Mahabharata 13.14.:

> **When the unrighteous or sinful Kali Yuga comes, one should never pass a moment without devoting his heart upon Mahadeva.** One that has drunk the Amrita constituted by the devotion to Hara, one becomes freed from the fear of the world (by getting moksha).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..