In which scriptures does Shiva support casteism?
In Mahanirvana Tantra, Shiva himself reportedly says the following:
Chapter 3:

Let the excellent Guru, ocean of kindness, next whisper the Mantra
seven times into the  right ear of the disciple if he be a Brahmana,
or into the left ear if he be of another caste  (135).

Chapter 8

The twice-born enter the stage of an ascetic by renunciation of the
crown-lock and sacred thread, and the Shudras and Samanyas by the
renunciation of the crown-lock only (263).

Chapter 9:

The Shudras and mixed castes have no sacred thread, and but nine
purificatory ceremonies; for the twice-born classes there are ten (5)
The sacramental rites from Garbhadhana to Chudakarana are common to
all castes. But for Shudras and Samanyas they must be performed
without Mantras (184).

Chapter 11:

If a Kshatriya, Vaishya, Shudra, or Samanya, O Thou of Beauteous Face!
goes with a Brahmana woman knowing her to be such, then his punishment
is castration (38-39)


The wicked man who enjoys the wife of one of a higher caste should be heavily fined, and kept on a diet of grains for three months (40)


if a man eats the food cooked by an anulom person (a child of intercaste marriage), he needs to fast for 3 days to purify himself (129)



If the children of the Brahma (same caste) wife are living or any of her
descendants be living, then the children of the Shaiva (any caste) wife shall not
inherit (267).

This is the only book that I have found where Shiva is reported to say such things.
In which other scriptures does Shiva support or promote caste discrimination?

Shiva is not supporting 'caste discrimination' rather teaching who must be initiated in what manner for advancement in spiritual life given the sociophysical differences & the roles played by the 4 varnas in Vedic society. Just like in a company, a clerk is not assigned the work of a CEO and vice versa though both hold importance in their own ways. So there's no mundane discrimination (if that's the question) being done here by Shiva.

@HariHara Thanks for this. It says mixed-caste which means biological children from parents of different varnas. I am adding another verses Sanskrit to Hindi translation to clarify this book is referring to intercaste marriage and birth. In fact, it says you should not eat food of person whose parents were from different castes otherwise you will get impure.

Consciousness transmits through food, no doubt. I think the "kuladharm se vidvesh karne wala" part holds the key to its meaning as inter-caste marriages mostly lead to offsprings who gradually drift away from Vedic culture as each generation passes i.e., reject it or become ignorant of shastras and no longer have interest. There'll certainly be exceptions like shudras, etc. who show appreciation or practice Vedic culture and chant Krishna Japa, etc. where quality of the person shall hold significance and not just birth as told in other shastras, and hence food may be accepted.

You are reading the previous verse (which I have not quoted) as it is referring to mlecchas, haters of Kula dharma, and yavanas. Verse 129 refers specifically to "anulom" people which means both parents are of Hindu jati. Brahmin father & Kshatriya mother also produces anulom child. In the "Shaiva marriage" also the woman can be Hindu but Shiva clearly says to discriminate against her.

Ok. So this verse may be hard to apply practically given the current influence of kali and only the qualities of the person need to be considered, imho. As per Gita 3.13, any food not offered in sacrifice first is sin anyways...

@HariHara The fact is this scripture says Shivji wants a man to discriminate against his wife, children other castes and mixed-castes - regardless of what the practical application will be!

I'm not a follower of this Tantra Shastra, so can't comment much on its authenticity. Maybe you can request @Rickross for an answer. Shambhu.

It seems to be authentic and spoken by Shiva: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32108/34973 So it's up to you to either accept it or try to know why certain things may have been said or reject it.

I don't know if there are any other scripture where Siva has said anything like that. Mahanirvana Tanta is a very late composition and such statements reflect the attitude of the times.
I would like to point out that there is no reason to accept such verses in Hindu scripture. Such verses are invalid according to the advice of Hindu scripture and should not be followed.
No discrimination

If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
it should not be practiced. It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
and even of Kama.

Kurma Purana I.2.54
Moreover such verses contradict what Siva has said in Mahabharata.

Maheshwara said, ‘..Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor
learning, nor offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring
upon one the regenerate status. Verily, the conduct is the only
ground. All Brahmanas in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of
conduct. A Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as
possessed of the status of a Brahmana. The status of a Brahma, O
auspicious lady [Uma], is equal wherever it exists. Even this is my
opinion. He, indeed, is a Brahmana in which the status of Brahma
exists – that condition which is bereft of attributes and which has no
stain attached to it. The boon giving Brahma, when he created all
creatures, himself said that the distribution of human beings in four
orders dependent on birth is only for purposes of classification.

Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXLIII
COMMENT
How do you know which scripture is right? Have you done Shiv/Bhairav Sadhna and asked him that question yourself?
Good question. You don't have to do sadhana. You just implement the advice given in Hindu scripture itself and the advice of the greats.
Reason

Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
doubts, that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
test of reason.

Mahabharata Shanti Parva Section CXLII
Acharya Shankara says:

The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is
misconceived. The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen
forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not
confined to the sphere of direct perceptions, etc ... Even a hundred
statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and non-luminous
won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its import will
have to be interpreted differently. Otherwise, validity won't attach
to it. Nothing in conflict with the means of valid cognition or with
its own statements may be imputed to sruti.

REF: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Bhasya 18.66 of Sri Sankaracarya translation by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier
Non-discrimination

If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
it should not be practiced. It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
and even of Kama.

Kurma Purana I.2.54
If a scriptural verse does advocate discrimination then don't follow that verse.
Conscience

The whole Veda is the (first) source of the sacred law, next the
tradition and the virtuous conduct of those who know the (Veda
further), also the customs of holy men, and (finally)
self-satisfaction.

Manu Smriti II.6
Hindu scripture can’t override reason and conscience. Nor can Hindu scripture be used to discriminate against a community. So any Hindu scriptural verse that violates these 3 requirements is to be discarded.

I know there are many scriptures where Shiva talks against caste system (I can name many more) but I am only asking for those scriptures where he is said to support and promote it.

I don't know in which scripture Shiva supports casteism. Shiva didn't support or promote casteism anywhere. It is the human authors who put these words in his mouth. Hinduism is not a centralized dharma. Thus all kinds of opinions are there in texts regarded as scripture. So Hindu scriptures themselves have given advice on how to read the scripture. Hindu scripture can't be used to discriminate against others regardless of what is written in any 'scripture'.

How do you know which scripture is right? Have you done Shiv/Bhairav Sadhna and asked him that question yourself?

I have answered above.

Thanks but Adi Shankara promoted casteism many times in his younger days - he also wrote down that nobody in the 4 mathas can become Shankaracharya except people born to Brahmin parents. He also violently attacked and killed Kapalika Shaivas..... and all 4 of his successors especially Puri Shankaracharya openly promote casteism even today.

Adi Shankara was wrong on this issue. Read Maneesha Panchakam for an alternate view on varna. His modern day followers should quietly stop supporting casteism which is not in any Hindu foundational text. Mahanirvana Tantra is not a foundational Hindu text.

As for MBH and Kurma Purana - there are many contradictions in these texts and they include instances of casteism. Anybody can also use these to support casteism

All these contradictions can be resolved by just following the non-discrimination rule and rejecting those verses that don't satisfy reason. Many contradictory verses exist because of two reasons. There has never been any central authority in Hinduism (like the Christian Church) to enforce quality control. The other reason is that before the invention of the printing press no book was safe from interpolation. So Hindu scripture has left  it to the wisdom of the reader to decide which verse should be accepted and which rejected.

Many believe Tantras are superior to Vedas or at the very least they are equal to Vedas. How do you know Adi Shankara was wrong? You are only quoting scriptures with many casteist and contradictory verses.... despite writing Manisha Panchakam (a short text) Adi Shankar never allowed a non-brahmin by birth to become his successor which means he stood by his earlier writings.

You don't have to accept my position. I think Shankara was wrong on both caste and other issues also. This is my opinion.

How do you know the interpolation was not done to favour equality? Maybe the original texts fully supported casteism like Shiva apparently himself wants in this Tantra shastra.
